# Android simplexml.jar proguard problem

Tags: android, proguard

I just try to parse a simple xml documention by simple-xml-2.6.jar.I put this jar into a folder named lib then add it in libraries .Then i attempt to skip this jar so code in the proguard.cfg just like below:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-libraryjars lib/simple-xml-2.6.jar
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**
-keeppackagenames  com.wang.demo
-keep public class org.simpleframework.** { *; }
-keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.core.** { *; }
-keep public class org.simpleframework.* { *; }
-keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.core.* { *; }
-keep public class org.simpleframework.* 
-keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.core.* 
-keep public class org.simpleframework.** { public protected *; }
-keep public class org.simpleframework.xml.core.** { public protected *; }
-keep public class javax.xml.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-keep public class * extends com.wang.demo.CommonResponse { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I want to cover all the  Exceptions but the logcat it shows:

```
08-25 17:06:56.886: WARN/System.err(8745): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: m(dm,Element)
08-25 17:06:56.886: WARN/System.err(8745):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
08-25 17:06:56.886: WARN/System.err(8745):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
08-25 17:06:56.886: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.at.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.be.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.q.b(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.q.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.b.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.av.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.dn.b(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ar.h(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ar.g(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ed.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.az.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.897: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Unknown Source)
08-25 17:06:56.907: WARN/System.err(8745):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Unknown Source)


So anyone help me fix it?
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

I thinks it is because `proguard` changed the name of `Annotation` attribute.
For example, annotation Attribute was defined as:

```
public @interface Attribute
{
    public String name() default "";
    public String empty() default "";
}
```

But after obfuscating, it becomes:

```
public @interface Attribute
{
    public abstract String a();
    public abstract boolean b();
}
```

Then, at runtime, the code will fail to get attribute name via reflection.

Comment: Same problem as well using Simple and Proguard. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: My problem was solved by adding the following config in proguard.cfg 
`-keep public class org.simpleframework.**{
 *;
}
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.**{
 *;
}
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{
 *;
}
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{
 *;
}`

Comment: I've tried this, as well as keeping all my classes that directly utilise the Simple library, but to no avail. I get parsing errors. Using -dontobfuscate makes it work, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: personally i only use pro-guard to remove unneeded code, the additional issues related with potential security gain are negligible.
Makes these lines perfect `-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`